# How to fail specific Robot keyword, but continue with test execution?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a question regarding Robot Framework. I have a code like this:

```
Run Keyword Unless    '${Value}'=='49'   Fail    Incorrect counter value
```

It works quite ok, but the keyword `Fail` stops test execution. How can I fail specific keyword, under which the above construction is nested, but carry on with execution of keywords in the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as below:

```
  Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Run Keyword Unless    '${Value}'=='49'   Fail    Incorrect counter value
```

This will let you to continue execution even if this step is failed

Answer (score 1):

There are three keywords available in BuiltIn:

- `Run Keyword And Continue On Failure`
- `Run Keyword And Expect Error`
- `Run Keyword And Ignore Error`

Consider to use the most suitable one for your purpose.
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure